# Unable to read data from contact picker

Tags: java, android

I am unable to read and handle the data of contact from my activity.
By executing my code , it displays a contact picker but when i select a contact it shows a dialog box as "Unfortunately YourApp has been stopped".
I am able to choose the contact but can't read the data as phone number,name etc.

I am quite sure that there is some mistake in onActivityResult() method

The code in onActivityResult() method is:-

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 1) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
 contact=data.getData();
 String projection[]={Phone.NUMBER};
 Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(contact, projection, null, null, null);
 c.moveToFirst();
 int column=c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
 String number=c.getString(column);
 Toast.makeText(this,"The number of selected contact is:-"+ number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

Please help me.
I am new to android programming.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is crash log you get in LogCat ? post it.Did you try debugging ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your onActivityResult should be like below

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri result = data.getData();  
           String id = result.getLastPathSegment();
            String projection[] = { Phone.NUMBER };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                    Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int column = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = c.getString(column);
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "The number of selected contact is:-" + number,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me why you have taken String id and passed it as an argument(Second last) in query method?

Comment: @Priyank Uri is the location as to where the file is located and getLastPathSegment() gives the id of the contact you have selected via ContactPicker

Comment: @Priyank  please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) for an understanding of query method on content provider

Comment: Can you please also tell me what was the problem in my code? @dora